# ABP framework: Dashboard not working in some tenants

Tags: asp.net-mvc, abp

Dears
I'm facing strange problem here Dashboard not appear in some tenants and works in perfect way in another tenants and host
and this is the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined"
Can anyone help in this strange error ?
[image]

in other tenants this error not appear so it works correctly Please help !!
Abp version 4.2 MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems ChartJS is missing in your bundle. Probably it might be defined in HostDashboard but not in TenantDashboard.

Make sure `ChartjsScriptContributor` is added to the page.

```html
    <abp-script type="typeof(ChartjsScriptContributor)" />
```

It's **not recommended** but you can add it to the global bundle:

```cs
Configure<AbpBundlingOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ScriptBundles.Configure(
        LeptonThemeBundles.Scripts.Global,
        bundle =>
        {
            bundle.Contributors.Add(new ChartjsScriptContributor());
            // ...
        }
    );
});
```